# Line String Self-Intersection points in PostGIS

Tags: postgis

I'm trying to get all the points from a Self-Intersection Line String but not find out the self intersection point in the below attached image.

The intersection point touches on the same feature how to find out the self intersection point in postGIS?

[image]

Comment: http://postgis.net/docs/ST_IsValidReason.html

Comment: I am used the ST_IsValidReason but it returns true in that above case

Comment: use a line of code in your script: st_isvalid (geom)=false

Comment: st_isvalid(geom)  return true in that feature. Here how to find out that point touches on the segment or vertex in self feature.

Comment: http://postgis.net/docs/ST_IsSimple.html

Answer (score 2):

PostGIS has a rich functionality, as an option you can solve your problem as follows:

> `select st_intersection(a.geom, b.geom) as geom 
>   from yuor_table_name as a, yuor_table_name as b
>   where st_touches(a.geom, b.geom);`

Try to dig deeper...